# Java 8 SortedList TableView not refreshing

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, java-8, sortedlist

I am using a TableView to visualize a SortedList backed up by an ObservableList.

The comparator of the SortedList is bound to the comparator of the TableView:

```
sortedList().comparatorProperty().bind(tableView.comparatorProperty());
```

The SortedList sorts as expected (by the comparator of the TableView chosen) when I add an item to the underlying ObservableList.

Although when I change a Property of the ObservableList (with a CheckBoxTableCell, but that shouldn't matter), the SortedList doesn't sort again.

Is this supposed to work or do I have to find a workaround?

I am using jdk 8 b121.

Comment: "*The comparator of the TableView is bound to the comparator of the SortedList*" => no the opposite. Is there a reason why you are using a sorted list? I would expect the sorting of the table view to be "refreshed" when the items list is mutated (add/remove) but not when an item itself is mutated. So you probably need to add a listener on the check box and re-sort the table programmatically.

Comment: I used SortedList mostly because it was new and thought it would be more efficient sorting. But the SortedList can't be manually sorted (there's probably a workaround) so I switched to displaying the ObservableList and it works (I had to call FXCollections.sort() on every change)

Comment: Actually, I also had to get the Comparator of the TableView manually for the .compareTo() function, but it works now!

Comment: @LukasLeitinger you should add an answer with your solution and accept it

Answer (score 2):

Note: this answer assumes that "change a property of the ObservableList" actually should read "change a property of an item of the ObservableList". It the assumption is incorrect, I'll delete.

A SortedList is *the* clean solution for sortable data in a TableView - it's designed and implemented to keep itself sorted when the wrapped list is changed. Provided, the backing list *notifies* its listeners about the change. That's working without needing additional client code for modifications to the list (like add/remove/set of items).

On the other hand, there is no general way it can know about modifications of properties of a contained item: client code must provide an extractor (aka callback that returns an array of Observables) that allows the list to fire update events to its listeners.

An example (Person a demo bean with obvious properties - replace with your favourite example bean), the edit-button simply prepends a "z" to the last name of the selected person.

```
public class TableViewSortSample extends Application {

    private Parent getContent() {
        // wrap the backing list into an observableList with an extractor
        ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableList(
                Person.persons(),
                person -> new Observable[] {person.lastNameProperty(), person.firstNameProperty()}            
        );
        // wrap the observableList into a sortedList
        SortedList<Person> sortedPersons = new SortedList<>(persons);
        // set the sorted list as items to a tableView
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>(sortedPersons);
        // bind the comparator of the sorted list to the table's comparator
        sortedPersons.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
        TableColumn<Person, String> firstName = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        TableColumn<Person, String> lastName = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstName, lastName);
        Button edit = new Button("Edit");
        edit.setOnAction(e -> {
            Person person = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (person != null) {
                person.setLastName("z" + person.getLastName());
            }
        });
        VBox pane = new VBox(table, edit);
        return pane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(getContent()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```