# How to observe items' properties changes in ObservableList

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, observablelist

I'm developing some messenger with JavaFX just to get more familiar with this technology.

`Contact` has two main properties: `User` and last `Message`.

I need to show

1. list of contacts with most recent messages
2. list of contacts sorted by name

I came to two solutions so far

**First solution** is to make `Contact` immutable. So it is required to replace contact every time a new message arrives or user's information changes. It works, but Contact **blinks** in ListView on update.

**Second solution** is to use `ObjectProperty`:

```
public class Contact {
    private final ObjectProperty<User> user = ...; 
    private final ObjectProperty<Message> lastMessage = ...; 
}
```

In that case I have to create custom ObservableList to add/remove listeners to `Contact`'s properties when `Contact` is added/removed to/from list. It's required because both lists should be automatically sorted.

So both solutions have drawbacks.

Please, give your recommendations on how to achieve my goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 SortedList TableView not refreshing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171948/java-8-sortedlist-tableview-not-refreshing)

Comment: yeah, it is - absolutely a very similar problem with the exact same remedy  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `FXCollections` class, there is one method that uses an "extractor" function to tell the list which properties from the list items should fire list change events:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-

This will give you the same approach as your second solution, but without you having to write the code to manage the listeners yourself.

Comment: Thank you! I missed that method and extractors somehow.